# MVC - Troubles displaying a list of items in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to C# and MVC and have become stuck on an issue. I'm trying to display a list of users on a page with the search functionality. However, when I open this page I only get the following displayed and the rest is blank :
[image]

Here is my UserListModel :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace GymWiz.Models
{
    public class UserListModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName {get; set;}
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int MembershipCardId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public int isActive { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I would like to control the displayed data via Ajax, so I am getting the data using MemberList() method would like to display the default results before any search keywords are entered.

```
 public class AdminUserController : Controller
{
    // GET: Admin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<UserListModel> mod = MemberList();
        return View(mod);
    }

    public PartialViewResult SearchUsers(string searchText)
    {
        List<UserListModel> model = MemberList();
        var searchResult = model.Where(a => a.FirstName.ToLower()
        .Contains(searchText) || a.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchText) ||
        a.Username.ToLower().Contains(searchText));

        return PartialView("_MemberListTable", searchResult);
    }

    public List<UserListModel> MemberList()
    {
        using (DBGymWizEntities db = new DBGymWizEntities())
        {
            var query = db.users.Where(user => user.Deleted.Equals(0)).ToList().Select(p => new UserListModel()
            {
                id = (int)p.id,
                Username = p.Username,
                FirstName = p.FirstName,
                LastName = p.LastName,
                MembershipCardId = (int)p.MembershipCardId,
                CreatedDate = p.CreatedDate,
                isActive = p.Active
            }).ToList();

            return query;
        }
    }
```

The partial view :

```
    @model List<GymWiz.Models.UserListModel>

<table class="table user-list" id="memberListTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><b>Name</b></th>
            <th><b>Joined Date</b></th>
            <th><b>Card ID</b></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var user in Model)
        {
          .....
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to show main view and ajax as well

Comment: Thank you all! After walking back from a computer and re-inspecting the code once again, I noticed that my Index method was of no use, since it had no triggers at all....In the end, I just had to rename the method to match the view